Customize size ranges in Windows Explorer File Search (F3)
In Windows Explorer we can search for files using the search bar accessible by F3. We can use advanced search options such as type: or size: to limit the result set. When using the size: filter, a dialog appears to suggest some ranges. These are labeled "Empty, Tiny, Small, Medium, Large, Huge, Gigantic" in English (and "Leer, Sehr klein, Klein, Mittel, Groß, Sehr groß, Riesig" in German). Each corresponds to a range specified in KB/MB/GB.
Now I'd like to customize these ranges. I imagine they're stored in the registry, possibly someplace below HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer. However, the following turns up nothing:
reg query hkcu\Software\Microsoft /s /f Gigantic
reg query hkcu\Software\Microsoft /s /f Riesig

Same for Windows, Windows Search and Windows Desktop Search under HKLM\Software\Microsoft. Is it configurable after all? If so, how?
Windows 10 22H2 in case it matters.

Workaround: use AutoHotkey or similar to paste a size range, e.g., size:>10000 AND size:<1000000. That single key combo might be faster than typing "gigantic".

@DrMoishePippik, thanks for the suggestion. I could also save the search as .search-ms file (XML) in %UserProfile%\Searches (via Explorer's "Search" menu), but here I'm more interested in customizing what Explorer already offers to fit my "file size habits" better rather than in solving a particular practical task.
